# mysql/workbench: why is on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP added for not null timestamp

Tags: mysql, attributes, timestamp, workbench

*brief:*

I'm experiencing strange MySQL behavior - **on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** attribute is being added although I don't want it to be added. I want to find out why is this happening - is it a matter of MySQL server or MySQL Workbench I'm using (v5.2.38).

*detail:*

I've modelled the database structure using EER diagrams, an example table is below:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `privilege` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'privilege name (just a label)' ,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL COMMENT 'when the privilege was created' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The above script fragment is created using *Export > Forward Engineer SQL Create Script* inside WorkBench. The **created_at** column is siginifant here. It is NOT NULL and there is no default value defined for the timestamp when a record is defined. So I guess, that if someone tries to insert a record without defining created_at, an error will be raised.

I run this script inside MySQL server to create the whole structure. And the created structure is different - *show create table privilege* returns the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `privilege` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'privilege name (just a label)',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'when the privilege was created',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Where did "on update current_timestamp" come from? I'm 100% sure that I didn't choose any appropriate option, so MySQL should not create anything he's not asked to.

Does anyone have an idea why those clauses are added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> The following rules describe the possibilities for defining the first [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) column in a table with the current timestamp for both the default and auto-update values, for one but not the other, or for neither:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - With neither `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` nor `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, it is the same as specifying both `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> To suppress automatic properties for the first [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) column, do either of the following:
>
> - Define the column with a `DEFAULT` clause that specifies a constant default value.
> - Specify the `NULL` attribute. This also causes the column to permit `NULL` values, which means that you cannot assign the current timestamp by setting the column to `NULL`. Assigning `NULL` sets the column to `NULL`.